# How Merge method of hibernate identifies if the object is to be saved or to be updated?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I Want to know, how hibernate comes to know whether the object is to be saved as a new one or updated.I mean i want to know exactly how merge works internally.

Answer (score 1):

It checks the entity id. If the id is set then we have an update, otherwise we have an insert. To check if the entity is attached or not it simply check the first level cache. If it's in the cache, then the entity is already attached.